# Exception handling in Mule ESB Flows: Multiple exception strategies

Tags: web-services, exception, mule, esb, mule-flow

I want to add exception handling in Mule ESB using custom-exception-strategy. However, I have multiple service calls in one flow, and I want to handle exceptions from each service call separately.

Is it possible to have multiple custom-exception strategies in a single flow? Right now, I am able to use only one custom-exception-strategy, and only when I place it at the end of the flow, after the last outbound endpoint. This is the expected behavior. All right. But I want to use multiple exception strategies in a flow.

The Mulesoft documentation says we have to use processor chains if we want to use multiple exception strategies. I am not sure how it will translate into the configuration XML. Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need place your different service calls in **private flows**.

Something like:

```
<flow name="main">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="in" />
    <flow-ref name="sub1" />
    <flow-ref name="sub2" />
</flow>

<flow name="sub1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <!-- do something -->
    <custom-exception-strategy>
        <!-- sub1 specific -->
    </custom-exception-strategy>
</flow>

<flow name="sub2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <!-- do something -->
    <custom-exception-strategy>
        <!-- sub2 specific -->
    </custom-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I figured out after a few trials that there was absolutely no way to put more than one exceptions strategy in one flow. Will try this style now. Though, one more thing. Say, I am putting something in the session scope in private flow sub1 above. (How do I) or (Do I get to) access it in the next private flow sub2?

Comment: I've tested and can confirm that session properties added in sub1 are available in sub2. Depending on the context, but one way to access such a session property is with an expression: `#[header:SESSION:fromSub1]`.

Comment: Thanks @David. I can access session properties just like you showed there. Now, I can also access them inside an XSLT transformer by passing it as a context-property to the transformer. Thanks.